How to make pull-request merge on github only by repository owner?
I have a repo on GitHub. I want to make the pull requests available merge only by me as a repo owner.

I'm assuming the repo isn't private?

@evolutionxbox repo might be private or public. Its managable

If you make the repo private, then noone else can make pull-requests.

@evolutionxbox i want to allow people make PRs but only me as owner can merge them

You can protect branches. Maybe you can use a wildcard to protect all branches?

@evolutionxbox not sure how to do that

https://docs.github.com/en/repositories/configuring-branches-and-merges-in-your-repository/managing-protected-branches/about-protected-branches

Unfortunately, GitHub doesn't provide a ruleset option to allow only specific users for merging pull requests. However, it does provide an option to allow only code owners for merging pull requests.
Code owners are specific users or teams that own certain files in the repository. This means that when the option Require review from Code Owners is enabled and a pull request contains commits that affect owned files, the pull request must be reviewed by the corresponding code owners before being able to merge it.

Code owners are automatically requested for review when someone opens a pull request that modifies code that they own. [...] When someone with admin or owner permissions has enabled required reviews, they also can optionally require approval from a code owner before the author can merge a pull request in the repository.

Code owners can be defined in a special configuration file called CODEOWNERS under a .github folder in the target branch.

To use a CODEOWNERS file, create a new file called CODEOWNERS in the .github/, root, or docs/ directory of the repository, in the branch where you'd like to add the code owners.

The CODEOWNERS syntax is similar to the .gitignore's one, where each line contains the file pattern followed by the user(s) or team(s) owning the files identified by the rule.

A CODEOWNERS file uses a pattern that follows most of the same rules used in gitignore files. The pattern is followed by one or more GitHub usernames or team names using the standard @username or @org/team-name format.

In your case, you could write a pattern where every file is matched, like *, and then add your GitHub username as the only owner.
# Your user will be the default owner for everything in
# the repo. Unless a later match takes precedence.
# Your user will be requested for review when someone opens a pull request.

*       @<your-user>

To create a code owner ruleset, go to your repository > Settings > Rules > Ruleset, and then create a new rule with:

Enforcement status set to Active.
The branches you wish the rule to be applied in the Target branches section.
The option Require a pull request before merging enabled.
The sub-option Required approvals set to 1.
The sub-option Require review from Code Owners enabled.

